# pycharm-package/main/main is does not exist in tmp how can i solve this?

Tags: python, pycharm

Shown here is the problem.

I have attached the prompt maybe you could help thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: i tried the recommended solution but i got the same error also.

Comment: You forgot to attach a description

Comment: Are you sure you know what are you doing? Do you really need `main` package from PyPI? It looks old and dead.